# How to let TypeScript know of added methods via class / component decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript

If I am decorating a Component with my own decorator, how do I let TypeScript know that I have added functionality (methods) to that class via `@MyComponentDecorator`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'MySelector',
    template: 'bar'

})
@MyComponentDecorator
export class MyClass {

    constructor(){
         this.myNewMethod('foo'); // TypeScript error as transpiler is not aware
    }
}
 ...
```

regards

Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up an interface with the same name:

```
interface MyClass {
    myNewMethod(str: string): void;
}
```

With this:

```
function MyComponentDecorator(constructor: { new (): MyClass }) {
    constructor.prototype.myNewMethod = function (str: string) {
        console.log(str);
    }
}

interface MyClass {
    myNewMethod(str: string): void;
}

@MyComponentDecorator
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
         this.myNewMethod('foo');
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20MyComponentDecorator(constructor%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20MyClass%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor.prototype.myNewMethod%20%3D%20function%20(str%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(str)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20myNewMethod(str%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%40MyComponentDecorator%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myNewMethod('foo')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

---

#### Edit

You can implement the interface with the class, but then you need to do this:

```
interface IMyClass {
    myNewMethod(str: string): void;
}

@MyComponentDecorator
class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    constructor() {
         this.myNewMethod('foo');
    }

    myNewMethod: (str: string) => void;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20MyComponentDecorator(constructor%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20MyClass%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor.prototype.myNewMethod%20%3D%20function%20(str%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(str)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IMyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20myNewMethod(str%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%40MyComponentDecorator%0Aclass%20MyClass%20implements%20IMyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myNewMethod('foo')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20myNewMethod%3A%20(str%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%7D))

If you don't add `myNewMethod` as property then it complains that:

```
this.myNewMethod('foo'); // Error: Property 'myNewMethod' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
```

Comment: Tx Nitzan, wouldn't I need to also set MyClass implement IName? I guess not per your answer, which is really cool... unfortuantly I can't use Decorators as Angular2 does not support it with AOT, so I have to opt to sub-classing a base class... tx for a great solution though.

Comment: Check my revised answer. Also, yeah, you need to export the interface if the class is exported. I remove the exports because it makes it easy to test in playground/console.

Comment: another caveat with this solution though is that you have to name each class that you will use the decorator with, as an Interface... :/

Comment: Well, you don't have much choice. Typescript is for compile time, but you're changing the class at runtime using the decorator. If you want the compiler not to complain and yet have type safety (otherwise just do `(this as any).whatever()`) then you need that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Tx to Tomer here is the final solution (beware as its not compatible with Angular AOT mode):

```
export function TakeUntilDestroy(constructor) {
    var original = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy;
    var subject;
    var unsub;
    constructor.prototype.componentDestroy = function () {
        subject = new Subject();
        return subject.asObservable();
    };
    constructor.prototype.unsubOnDestroy = function (i_unsub) {
        unsub = i_unsub;
    };
    constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
        original && typeof original === 'function' && original.apply(this, arguments);
        unsub === 'function' && unsub();
        subject && subject.next('ngOnDestroy') && subject.unsubscribe();
    };
}


export interface AdnetConfigTargets {
    unsubOnDestroy(i_value:Function): void;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'AdnetConfigTargets',
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    template: AdnetConfigTargetsTemplate

})
@TakeUntilDestroy
export class AdnetConfigTargets {

    constructor(private appStore: AppStore) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.unsubOnDestroy(()=>{
                console.log('do something when Component is destroyed')
            }
        );
    }

}
```